# Using Laravel Passport to only access own account on a few Routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport, api-authorization

My whole application has a lot of api routes that serve my frontend with ajax responses. I use Laravel Passport xsrf token protection to protect my routes and manage authentication. However, we are planning to serve an api that a specific type of user can consume. To go in more detail, here is a (fictional) example of what we want to achieve:

A company can have a lot vacancies. 
My api routes are a lot, now I want to give the company owner the ability to get all his vacancies over our sdk and place them on his website. The Problem I am facing: As far as I understand passport correctly, personal access tokens are the thing I need. I don’t want a „log in with my application“ functionality (jet), how do I disable this? I want only the user to access his own informations, not from other users.  And I probably want in the future to let the user register for different apis. So that he has multiple access tokens for different routes, but the routes are all together in one api.php routes file. I think I would need to use scopes for this, but how do I safely assign the scopes to the tokens, since this only does a single route?

Can someone help me to understand the concept of passport correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use passport, however it seems this issue could be solved with scopes (not needing to be tied to an access token). If you are struggling with getting the authenticated user, you could follow this post:
[Get authenticated user with Laravel Passport and grant password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997516/get-authenticated-user-with-laravel-passport-and-grant-password)

If you are struggling with how to write your scope, here is what I am thinking

- You have a table containing companies called `companies`
- You have a table containing employees called `employees`
- You have a table containing vacancies called `vacancies`
- You have a join table called `company_employee`

Now you can create a scope on your `Vacancy` model

```
class User {
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\CompanyEmployee::class)
    }
}

class Employee {

}

class Company {

}

class CompanyEmployee {

}

class Vacancy {
    public function scopeMine($query)
    {
        $my_companies = auth()
            ->user()
            ->companies()
            ->select('company_id')
            ->pluck('company_id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

        return $query->whereIn('company_id', $my_companies);
    }
}
```

Then no matter how you are querying the vacancies (through an API or front end GUI), you can simply add the scope to your query presumably in your controller.

```
class VacancyController {
    public function index()
    {
        return App\Vacancy::mine()->get();
    }
}
```